# как прижать текст в lable к правому краю

Tags: python, tkinter

вот пример:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Калькулятор")
window.geometry("400x600")
window.resizable(False, False)
canvas = Canvas(window, width=400, height=400, bg='white')

font_settings = ("Times New Roman", 40, "")
virtualImg = PhotoImage()


resultLabel = Label(window, text="0", font=font_settings, image=virtualImg, width=380, height=75, compound=CENTER, bg="grey77")
resultLabel.place(x=10, y=10)


mainloop()
```

необходимо текст из resultLable прижать к правой части этого lable. помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь опцией [`anchor`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_anchors.htm):

```
resultLabel = Label(window, text="0", font=font_settings, image=virtualImg, width=380, height=75, compound=CENTER, bg="grey77", anchor="e")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое